# Is a sidekiq job left on sleep() consumes memory or it frees the memory until it continues after sleep?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sleep, sidekiq

I want to fetch a report from a specific URL but it has 2 steps one is to generate the Report request and other one is to fetch the report when it's ready. It usually takes around 10 minutes to  generate the report before fetching so i was thinking of using sleep() for 10 minutes and then try again.

I am considering if it takes same memory consumption on sleep() as well or not?